# Выполнение условия при достижении div-ом низа экрана

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, чтобы когда низ блока достиг низа экрана сработало условие в скрипте.

Никак не могу понять, в чем ошибка

```
window.onload = function(){
  var point_wrap = document.getElementById('point_wrap');
  var w_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var point_wrapSourceBottom = point_wrap.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset - w_height;

  window.onscroll = function() {

    if(window.pageYOffset > point_wrapSourceBottom) {
        условие, которое нужно выполнить
    }
  };
};
```

Если нужен конкретный код HTML, то добавлю. Но пока просто поясню, что блок `#point_wrap` находится не сверху экрана и имеет не нулевую высоту. Если заменить `w_height` на числовое значение высоты окна браузера (621 у меня), то код работает как надо.

И микро вопрос попутный. Почему в Хроме не отображаются переменная `point_wrapSourceBottom` в f12, даже когда скрипт работает?

Comment: `html` в студию

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился заменой `document.documentElement.clientHeight` на `document.body.clientHeight` Правда не до конца понял насколько это кроссбраузно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
var w_height = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

-...может в этом дело.

Comment: нет, без разницы